# JSON deserialize output to Textbox

Tags: c#, json

First time working with JSON and trying to figure this one out. I am able to connect to the API and get the JSON string to display in my textbox. I am confused on how to properly display the data correctly in the textbox.

This my code I have.

```
            {
            GetReportList p = new GetReportList();

            var client = new RestClient(p.WebReportList);
            client.Timeout = -1;
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
            request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "Value");
            var thisJsonStr = "{\"Credentials\": { \"ApiKey\": \"xxxxxxxx\",\"MerchantID\": \"xxxxxxx\",\"StoreID\":\"xxxxx\",\"Username\": \"xxxxx\",\"Password\": \"xxxx\"},\"ReportID\": [\"34\"]}";
            request.AddParameter("application/json", thisJsonStr, ParameterType.RequestBody);
            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

            deseiralizeObject = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Report>(response.Content);

            ReportListbx.Text = (response.Content);
         
        }
```

My output looks like this when I debug it.

```
{"Result":"OK","Reports":[{"ReportID":"18","Name":"END OF DAY","Type":"group"},{"ReportID":"34","Name":"MANDY REPORT","Type":"group"},{"ReportID":"17","Name":"Lottery Paid Out","Type":"preset"}
```

My output i want it to be the "ReportID","name", Type"
Thanks

@Saeed Aghdam

I have edited the code to this

```
             request.AddParameter("application/json", thisJsonStr, ParameterType.RequestBody);
            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

             var json = response.Content;

            var deseiralizeObject = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Report>(json);

            foreach (var report in deseiralizeObject.Reports)
            ReportListbx.Text = ($"{report.ReportID} - {report.Name} - {report.Type}");
```

And I get the last record from the JSON data.
[image]

Comment: @Flydog57 that's a setting related to serialization. not for deserialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I write a very simple console application, in this app, it gets your provided sample JSON and deserializes it to a class. so you can iterate items (elements) and display them.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    public class Report
    {
        public string Result { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<ReportItem> Reports { get; set; }
    }

    public class ReportItem
    {
        public string ReportID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var json = @"{""Result"":""OK"",""Reports"":[{""ReportID"":""18"",""Name"":""END OF DAY"",""Type"":""group""},{""ReportID"":""34"",""Name"":""MANDY REPORT"",""Type"":""group""},{""ReportID"":""17"",""Name"":""Lottery Paid Out"",""Type"":""preset""}]}";
            var deseiralizeObject = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Report>(json);

            foreach(var report in deseiralizeObject.Reports)
                Console.WriteLine($"{report.ReportID} - {report.Name} - {report.Type}");

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: An alternative for the above method is using a dynamic object, the following code do the same as the above codes are doing:

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    public class Report
    {
        public string Result { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<ReportItem> Reports { get; set; }
    }

    public class ReportItem
    {
        public string ReportID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var json = @"{""Result"":""OK"",""Reports"":[{""ReportID"":""18"",""Name"":""END OF DAY"",""Type"":""group""},{""ReportID"":""34"",""Name"":""MANDY REPORT"",""Type"":""group""},{""ReportID"":""17"",""Name"":""Lottery Paid Out"",""Type"":""preset""}]}";

            dynamic d = JObject.Parse(json);

            foreach (var report in d.Reports)
                Console.WriteLine($"{report.ReportID} - {report.Name} - {report.Type}");

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: ok but the line of 'var json = @"{""Result"":""OK"",""Reports"":' the data is never the same from site to site. so what would be the option for that.

Comment: The idea behind deserializing is you've to create the exact model of the input as I've done. but If you're working with different web APIs and you don't want to create the models, so you can use a dynamic object as I've done in the second part of the answer.

Comment: I am not explaining right here. The body that is coming from the API is dynamic in what is sent. So one day it can xxx then the next day they create a new report and the it will xxy and or if the remove a report.

Comment: From what you're saying, I suggest you `Regex`, so you can extract Name, Id, and Type from the JSON. All you need in Regex is a pattern to extract desired information.